# how to map fluentd configuration via configmap using volumes in K8s

Tags: kubernetes, fluentd, efk

Issue here is its copying my entire fluentd-confg.yaml instead of creating fluent.conf file in the fluentd containers. I added the `subPath: fluent.conf` into volumeMounts and after that there is no any file created inside any of my fluentd containers. Why its not creating fluent.conf file inside my containers?

Below file is my fluentd-confg.yaml file.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: fluentd-config
  namespace: surf-lite
data:
  fluent.conf: |
    <source>
      @type tail
      format none
      path /var/log/*.log
      pos_file /var/log/fluentd_pos_files/*.log.pos
    </source>
    <match **>
      @type elasticsearch
      host 192.168.4.24
      port 9200
      index_name mylogs
      logstash_format true
    </match>
```

Below file is my fluentd-daemonset-elasticsearch-rbac.yaml file

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: fluentd
  namespace: surf-lite
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: fluentd
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - pods
  - namespaces
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
---
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: fluentd
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: fluentd
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: fluentd
  namespace: surf-lite
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: fluentd
  namespace: surf-lite
  labels:
    k8s-app: fluentd-logging
    version: v1
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: fluentd-logging
      version: v1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: fluentd-logging
        version: v1
    spec:
      serviceAccount: fluentd
      serviceAccountName: fluentd
      tolerations:
      - key: node-role.kubernetes.io/control-plane
        effect: NoSchedule
      - key: node-role.kubernetes.io/master
        effect: NoSchedule
      containers:
      - name: fluentd
        image: fluent/fluentd-kubernetes-daemonset:v1.16.1-debian-elasticsearch7-1.2
        env:
          - name: K8S_NODE_NAME
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                fieldPath: spec.nodeName
          - name: FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_HOST
            value: "192.168.4.24"
          - name: FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_PORT
            value: "9200"
          - name: FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_SCHEME
            value: "http"
          - name: FLUENTD_SYSTEMD_CONF
            value: 'disable'
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: 200Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 200Mi
        volumeMounts:
        - name: varlog
          mountPath: /var/log
        - name: config-volume
          mountPath: /fluent.conf
          subPath: fluent.conf
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      volumes:
      - name: config-volume
        configMap:
          name: fluentd-config
      - name: varlog
        hostPath:
          path: /var/log/pods
```